# CUPS crashes, and error messages

Tags: 22.04, printing

Ubuntu 22.04 (wayland), CUPS 2.4.1, hplip is not installed (does that matter???).

I keep getting error messages relating to CUPS and hpfax that I don't understand.

In /var/log/cups/error_log, here is an example of the messages I'm getting:

`E [04/Jan/2023:07:40:23 -0600] [cups-deviced] PID 1741 (hpfax) stopped with status 1! E [04/Jan/2023:07:40:34 -0600] [Client 6] Unable to encrypt connection: Error in the push function. E [04/Jan/2023:07:40:44 -0600] [Client 9] Unable to encrypt connection: Error in the push function. E [04/Jan/2023:07:40:54 -0600] [Client 12] Unable to encrypt connection: Error in the push function. E [04/Jan/2023:07:41:05 -0600] [Client 13] Unable to encrypt connection: Error in the push function.`

And here is what keeps showing up in /var/crash/_usr_lib_cups_backend_hpfax.0.crash:

`
PythonArgs: ['/usr/lib/cups/backend/hpfax']
Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/cups/backend/hpfax", line 83, in 
from base.g import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base.g'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/cups/backend/hpfax", line 89, in 
bug("Error importing HPLIP modules: %s\n" % (pid, e))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
UserGroups: N/A
`

I have two HP printers attached to this computer, as far as I can tell I am able to use them as I wish.  But I keep getting these error messages, and:

1. They're an annoyance; and far more importantly,
2. Something is clearly wrong, I'd like to have a properly working system.

Looking for help:

A)  What are these messages telling me?
B)  What is the problem?
C)  How do I fix the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Error importing HPLIP modules` -  in my eyes, this is an indication that you need `hplip` installed. It contains support for a number of hp and compatible devices; the likelihood of "getting things to work" increases with it installed.

Comment: Hannu - Thanks for the suggestion, I tried that, it seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hannu's suggestion to install the hplip package appears to have solved this problem for my system.